# How to plot a time-course experiment with two points per time?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have this kind of file of a time-course experiment with control and treatment situations:

```
Genes   C1    C2    C4    T1    T2    T4
YAL054C 10.59 10.93 11.70 13.15 13.97 14.14 
YAL062W 10.84 11.12 11.29 12.26 12.88 13.04
YAR035W 10.64 10.78 10.72 11.33 11.68 12.00 
YBL023C 10.61 10.85 10.33 10.37 9.88  9.67
```

I have many gene expression values in 2 experimental situations (control and treatment) collected at 3 different time-points (1 hour, 2 hours, and 4 hours). I need a graph that would have the three time-points in the x-axis (it would be "two points" at time 1, being C1 and T1, and so on), the expression values in the y-axis (in the data presented, it would go from 9.67 to 14.14) and each line would be a gene name. Then, all the control condition points would have a color and the treatment condition would have another color.

I've tried using a code from ggplots2 that I found here on Stackoverflow:

```
ggplot (a, aes(a$V1, y=value, color = variable)) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V2, col = "red")) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V3, col = "red")) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V3, col = "red")) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V4, col = "blue")) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V5, col = "blue")) 
+ geom_line(aes(y = a$V6, col = "blue"))
```

But even that I got to print all the cases, I couldn't find a way to print using only three points (instead of six).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to reformat your data into a long format in order to get it to work with ggplot.  I fabricated some data in a long format and made the kind of graph I think you're looking for.

```
df <- data.frame(gene = rep(1:4, each = 6),
                 type = rep(c("C", "T"), 12),
                 time = rep(c(1, 2, 4), 8),
                 value = rnorm(24))

ggplot(df, aes(time, value, col = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ gene)
```